# Run capistrano tasks as different user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm a newbie with capistrano, and have been banging my head against this problem for a couple of days so would really appreciate some help.

We have an annoying security setup, which means that i cannot run capistrano tasks on the remote server as the ssh user. It's a simpler version of [This problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578520/run-deployment-task-as-different-users) - which doesn't seem to have a working answer.

Edit:
Delving further into this, I find that i can do something like:

```
run "su - newuser" do |channel, stream, data|

          channel.send_data("#{password}\n")

          channel.send_data("rm -rf #{release_path}\n")

        end }
```

I can use this to overwrite the default deploy methods, and do most of what I need to do. I can create the required directories on the server and so on, and pull from git as the ssh user using ssh forwarding.  Which creates my next problem.  I now have directories owned by newuser which contain files and directories owned by ssh_user.  I do have sudo privileges as newuser, but can't work out how to chmod the files.  I've tried stuff like:

```
run "su - newuser" do |channel, stream, data

              channel.send_data("#{password}\n")

              channel.send_data("sudo chmod 775 #{cache_path}\n")

            end }
```

but everything just hangs, and it seems as if the block is executed in an infinite loop. Obviously there is a lot i don't understand here and some pointers would be much appreciated - even if just to a good relevant read.

Comment: So you want to connect as one user, and then `sudo su` to another user?  If you were to manually login to the server what steps would you take?

Comment: correct - i can't sudo but i can su - see the comment to the answer below for a bit more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-Invocation-Run
shows you the :shell option for run which you can set to:

```
run "your cmd", :shell => "su - other_user -s bash"
```

if you use predefined tasks, you better redefine run and su to merge the shell option. 
this assumes your ssh user can su without password. if not use a block to send the password:

```
run "your cmd", :shell => "su - other_user -s bash" do |channel, stream, data|
  channel.send_data("#{other_user_password}\n")
end
```

Comment: This is very close to the sort of thing I've been trying, and can't get to work.  I can su - to the new user in the block, i get back the prompt in the data which suggests that the su was successful - but then I can't actually do anything more - obviously I'm missing something ...

Comment: that's the core of the problem -the ssh user is not in the sudoers list

Answer (score 0):

The solution I finally came up with was to take all the existing deploy tasks, and put them in a new namespace.  I then called the scripts they run with a new method, depending on whether I needed to run them as newuser or root, which although not identical to Viktor's solution is so close that I'm accepting his answer even though it didn't quite work for me

```
    def run_as(user, password, command, env)
      run "#{command}\n", :shell => "su - #{user}", :env => env do |channel, stream, data|   
        channel.send_data("#{password}\n")
      end
end
```